# Boot Camp Assistant - Setup from SD Card

Tags: bootcamp, sd-card

I am trying to install Windows 7 using the Boot Camp Assistant. I have downloaded the ISO, however I don't have a CD drive as its a MacBook Air and all my USB drives are too small. I am trying to install it using an SD Card as I read that they are handled in the same way as USB drives, however I can't find a way to get the assistant to recognise the SD card. Can any one help?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that as neither, OSX nor W7/W8 support booting from an SD card.

Get a simple usb-sd card adapter (not a multi card reader) and that'll work. In fact its what i used a micro-sd card in a usb adapter with an old 8gb card.

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently installing Windows 7 from an 16 GB SD card. From a Windows computer, I prepared the SD card with [WinToFlash](http://wintoflash.com/home/en/) and the ISO of Windows 7, and when it was done I mounted the SD card with a multi card reader, and Boot Camp read it!

Answer (score 2):

This is partially inaccurate. You can actually install OS X on a SD card according to Apple's support documents. However, on Windows you can't.

> **Can I install Mac OS X on an SD storage device and use it as a startup volume?**
>
> Yes. Change the default partition table to GUID using Disk Utility, and format the card to use the Mac OS Extended file format to do so.

Source: [Apple Support Article HT3553 About the SD and SDXC card slot, #12](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3553#12)

Comment: Does not work, Bootcamp is still saying 'No USB device found'

Answer (score 0):

You **can** boot from a SD card — I've booted Windows 7 and Windows 8 from a SD card.

You need to find a program that will mount the image file onto the SD card and make sure  you format Properly you can find out more information by just going on Google.